# Passing a struct to function in diffrent file in c

Tags: c, struct, include

I have two seperat files

in main function file 1:

```
struct entity{
        
        unsigned int pos_x;
        unsigned int pos_y;

        unsigned int health;
        
        
    } player;

    struct inventory{

            char helmet[length_item_names];
            char body[length_item_names];
            char legs[length_item_names];

            char items[inventory_space];

    } items;

    render_screen(rendered_size_x, inventory_size_x, screen_size_y, map, player, items);
```

file 2:

```
void render_screen(int render_size_x, int inventory_size_x, int screen_size_y, char **field, struct entity player, struct inventory items){

    ...

}
```

when declaring render_screen i either get a error telling me that the struct entity and struct inventory can't be declared as incomplete data types or when i do

```
extern struct Player{
...
}
```

it tells me that the data type i give as a parameter is wrong

how can i give the struct as a prameter

Comment: Put the structure declaration in a header file, which you include in both C files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of Barmar workerd.

I had to put the declaration of the struct into a header file that i had to include in both c files.

Thanks for the quick help